# What about electromagnetic waves of power cables?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency

**Edit**

I need to know about: low frequency electromagnetic waves in lower stages than radio waves. Here is picture of the region I'm interested in

[image]

What can you say about frequency of power cables in this range? What about electromagnetic waves of power cables? How harmful they are? What function they do?

**Edit**

According new picture I have found there are more things in lower frequency than radio waves.

[image]

Power lines are in range <100kHz

Strong magnets, MRI are in range 0Hz

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-ionizing_radiation#Health_risks

Comment: What more than *they're low frequency e&m waves* are you looking for ?

Comment: What is that? Isn't to low frequency to do something? Is there something more than power cables in this range(0-3 Hertz)? Can it be wind, aurora, clouds, lightening... etc...? I need more information about range between 0 and 3 Hz. I can't find any information about that.

Comment: Why do you think that *electromagnetic waves* can be "wind, aurora, clouds lightening... etc"? You do know what [electromagnetic waves are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation), right?

Comment: Yes I do. I need to know things from this range (0-3 HZ). Nobody answers to me. I don't think that everything ends with just 3 hertz. There is something more, but I can't find information about that.

Comment: Well if you know what electromagnetic waves are, then why did you ask if it was 1 of 4 things it *clearly isn't?*

Comment: Can you explain with more details, i need information for slides from this range below 3Hz. What can I say about this?

Comment: There are emission lines well below 3hz, for instance $H109\alpha$ is about 0.3 Hz

Comment: Ok, then emission lines, how do we get signal using emisssion lines?... Do somebody uses them to get signal in longer distances, but in lower frequency? Easy to detect or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ELF extremely low frequency electromagnetic waves are the same as all other electromagnetic waves. Just a bunch of photons that happen to have a low oscillating frequency. Their frequency is so Low that even traveling along at the speed of light they complete an oscillation within one to ten meters. They have been used to communicate with submarines because they can penetrate through the deep sea better than others.

Comment: According "Electromagnetic Radiation Spectrum" there is something more in lower frequencies than radio waves. Radio lower frequency is (3–30 Hz) and it named Extremely low frequency. So radio waves frequency ends with 3 hertz. But there is something different with It's wavelength (in metres) ranges from 10^5 to 10^8 and frequency (in hertz) ranges from 10^3 to 10^0 as in picture. So what happens if frequency ranges from 0 to 3 Hz?

Comment: The only thing different with ELF is the photons oscillate slower. Their no different from the photons that make up radio or gamma waves. They just have an Extremely Low Frequency. I don't know what the slowest photon oscillation is but I'm sure we can't detect it yet. Photons don't make wind, rain clouds or anything like that. Photons are just individual packets of energy each one oscillating on its own at some frequency. A so called radio wave has photons that oscillate about 1,000,000 cycles per second. The photons you are asking about oscilate 1 to 3 cycles per second. That's all

Comment: Do you know anything about power cables and it's low frequency?

Comment: @SineWave - Frequencies below 3 Hz are still RF. It's just that the antennas required to efficiently transmit or receive them are so large that nobody bothers. As a result, there is no formal name for that frequency range. But it's still RF. Emission by power cables (50 or 60 Hz) is well-known, and there is a whole movement devoted to the proposition that such emissions are harmful.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast It's clear about RF(Radio frequencies). I need more expanded answer about: power cables frequencies; What about power cable electromagnetic fields? Do they have any specific function? How harmful they are? This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @SineWave - They have no "function". When you run AC current you get emissions. As to how harmful they are, there is no obvious reason they should be harmful, but that has not stopped a lot of people from getting their panties in a twist. Who knows? They may be right.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast What is the lowest frequency (in Hz) dangerous to human? What range is it? Do you know more "harmful" things giving emission with ELF frequency except power cables? Can it cause cancer or other diseases?

Comment: @SineWave - Sigh. Will you at least do a _little_ work? Google "powerline radiation".

Answer (score -3):

A clarification: Radio waves are modulated electromagnetic radiation. Means, that this radiation is switched on and off with the frequency of the wave generator.

To get a satisfyIng result, the generator has to fit into a [LC circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LC_circuit).

[image: from Wikipedia]

The frequency of the involved photons are totally different from the frequency of the radio wave and could be in the range from infrared to gamma. So drive a antenna system with a low frequency and a powerful enough generator, and you get in any way the low radio frequency. But than shorter your antenna rod than less effectiv is your system and you will heat the rod (like a black body) more than emit effectively with the needed modulation a radio wave.

Comment: The photons involved in rf propagation have rf frequencies, not optical or higher frequencies.

Comment: @The Photon http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224078/how-exactly-do-radio-waves-work/224098#224098

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. The answer you linked to is really awful.